# Markup for HTML5 Image Gallery

Tags: html, semantic-markup, html5-canvas

I'm working on moving some Photoshop comps into code and have reached a point where I need to markup a small image gallery area. It exists in a sidebar and doesn't relate directly to the content on the page. As a result I believe I shouldn't use the `<figure>` element as that's supposed to be used to support existing content.

Suggestions on how to mark this up? Simple unordered list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about an `aside` tag ( http://html5doctor.com/aside-revisited/ )